# What does "for (; --i >= 0; )" mean in C?

Tags: c, loops

What does `for (; --i >= 0; )` mean in C?

How is the counter getting decremented and how is it different from `for ( ; i >= 0; --i)`?

Comment: Better to read how loop works. Read this article
http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-for-loop

Comment: This `for (; --i >= 0 ;)` code doesn't make sense because it's equivalent to `while (--i >= 0)` so what is a good reason for using a for loop?

Comment: If you didn't already saw it you can take a tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how this site works!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the name of the "-->" operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are very similar, but *not* the same! First you have to understand how a `for` loop in C gets executed:

As an example:

```
      1      2, 5  4
      |      |     |
      v      v     v
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // Do something <-- 3
}
```

As you can see 2, 3, 4, 5 is a loop until the condition is false.

Now you should clearly see how the for loop gets executed. The difference now is that in your first example:

```
int i = 5;
for ( ; --i >= 0; )
    printf("%d\n", i);
```

The output would be:

```
4
3
2
1
0
```

Because after the first check of the condition (Point 2), it executes the code block of the `for` statement and `i` already gets decremented.

In your second example:

```
int i = 5;
for( ; i>=0; --i)
    printf("%d\n", i);
```

The output would be:

```
5 // See here the difference
4
3
2
1
0
```

Here you get the difference, because it gets decremented in Point 4, so the first time it runs with the value 5.

Comment: Thank you. :)
Got it (y)

Answer (score 3):

These constructs are formally equivalent to

```
while (--i >= 0)
{
  Body;
}
```

and

```
while (i >= 0)
{
  Body;

  --i;
}
```

Do you better see the difference?

Answer (score 1):

In general, we can convert any `for` loop or `while` loop into a set of mostly linear statements with a `goto`. Doing this may be helpful to compare the code.

#### Case 1

```
### for (; --i >= 0; ) { statements; }
  ;                            // Initializer statement
start:
  bool condition = (--i >= 0); // Conditional
  if (condition) {             // If true, we execute the body as so:
    statements;                // The statements inside the loop
    ;                          // Empty increment statement
    goto start                 // Go to the top of the loop.
  }
```

#### Case 2

```
### for( ; i>=0; --i) { statements; }
  ;                            // Initializer statement
start:
  bool condition = (i >= 0);   // Conditional
  if (condition) {             // If true, we execute the body as so:
    statements;                // The statements inside the loop
    --i;                       // Increment statement
    goto start;                // Go to the top of the loop.
  }
```

#### Let's compare the "simpler" code from those two cases.

In the first case, we decrement `i` for the first time **before** each loop body. In the second case, we decrement `i` **after** each loop body.

The easiest way to see that is to consider what happens when you enter this loop when `i == 0`. In the first case, after this block of code, you would have a resulting value of `i == -1`. In the second case, `i` wouldn't have changed (that is, `i == 0`), because we never reached the increment statement.

Answer (score 0):

`for (; --i >= 0; )` works like this:

Say if you have i as 10, it will decrement the i value and will compare 9 >= 0 and so on.

So the output would be like `9, 8... till 0`.

While the loop `for( ; i>=0;--i)` would first go to 10, then decrement the value and then it would check i>=0. So the output would be `10, 9, 8... till 0`.

Answer (score 0):

The first one decrements `i` and then checks the condition.

The second one checks the condition first and if true, decrements `i` after the loop body has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

The three parameters (`initialization`, `condition` and `increment`) in `for` are optional (but they still requires the semicolon `;`). So, you can safely write `for(;;)` and it's the same as `while(1)`. So, expressions like

`for(; x > y; x++) { ... }`

`for(;1;x++) { if(x > y) break;`

`for(;;) { if(x++ > y) break;`

`for(;x++ > y;) { ... }`

Are valid and equivalent. In this, the increment occurs in the conditional parameters, just like in your code example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is the same as saying `for( i=0 or some value; --i <= 0 ; do nothing){}`
and `--i` is an predecrement operator.

That means when this piece of code, i.e., `--i`, is being read, the value of `i` will decrease by `1` at the same moment.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main components in a `for` loop.

Initialization, condition, and afterthought.

Initialization happens *once* at the start of the entire statement. Condition happens *before* every cycle. Afterthought comes *after* every cycle. Consider `i` starts at 2:

```
for (; --i >= 0; )

Initialization: i = 2
Condition: i = 1
Afterthought: i = 1
Condition: i = 0
Afterthought: i = 0
Condition: i = -1
Exit
```

In the other case

```
for( ; i>=0; --i)
Initialization: i = 2
Condition: i = 2
Afterthought: i = 1
Condition: i = 1
Afterthought: i = 0
Condition: i = 0
Afterthought: i = -1
Condition: i = -1
Exit
```

You can see that the second version actually lasts one cycle longer!

Comment: *Afterthought*? LOL :-)